# Storing data in JSON object to avoid multiple calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In the process of implementing this feature and wanted to get some suggestions.

When a user lands on this one page on my site, I get the user's connections from linkedin (via an API call). Now I need to display these connections on my page 10 connections at a time for some further processing. After loading the first 10 initially I want to give the user an option to load 10 more connections (by hitting a button), and then 10 more, etc.

I was thinking of implementing this in such a way that when user arrives on page, I make the API call, get all connections at one time, store them all into a JSON object and then display the first 10. If the user asks for the next 10, then I read the next 10 from the JSON object.

Is this the best way I can achieve this paging ability? Is using a JSON object a good way of going about it? Note, idea here is to prevent making muletiple API calls since Linkedin has a daily limit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like this method, especially for something like Autocomplete where there will be a server-side request every time the user makes a keystroke. I noticed that it was putting a lot of strain on my server (because the autocomplete gets used on the app almost 24/7). So I'll use an example from my code for you to adapt. It's for entering in playlists.

I have an action in my `PlaylistEntriesController` called `playlist` which respond to JS:

```
  def playlist
    @all_playlist_entries = PlaylistEntry.scoped # just a dump of all the playlist entries for autocomplete
  end
```

Then in `playlist.js.erb`:

```
<% cache 'playlist_entries', :expires_in => '1.day' do %>
    var titles = <%=raw @all_playlist_entries.map(&:title).uniq.to_json %>
    var artists = <%=raw @all_playlist_entries.map(&:artist).uniq.to_json %>
    var albums = <%=raw @all_playlist_entries.map(&:album).uniq.to_json %>
    var autocomplete_options = { delay: 100, autoFocus: true, minLength: 3 };
<% end %>
```

And then I simply pass those javascript variables as the "source" for the autocomplete. It's FAST (tested with 100,000 entries, database response time was something like 4 seconds and the actual autocomplete is still almost immediate), and even better, it only requires one call to the database each day, since it's cached, as opposed to THOUSANDS. The downside is, of course, that new entries won't be available until the next day, but in my case that is not a big issue.

So this is not exactly how you would implement it, but it will work. You can make one call to the LinkedIn API and store the results in a javascript array as json objects (using `to_json`, which you can override in the model if you need to). Then have a link that says `Show 10 more`, which will do some jQuery magic to show the next ten (I can't do it off the top of my head but it will be a matter of finding out how many are showing, either with a javascript variable or storing the number as a `data-attribute` or `id` on each DIV, and then getting the next 10 in the array).

Comment: bricker, thanks!! will try out your suggestion and get back soon.